# How to fetch files in dataorder using FindFirstFiles

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to retrieve the file names on the basis of Date order. Currently i am using FindFirstFiles function to retrieve the files.I am getting the file names in alphabetical order(ascending) but i want to receive it on the bases of File data. How could we achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with "bases of File data?

FindFirstFiles doesn't return files in any sorted order: 
_.. This may or may not be the first file or directory that appears in a directory-listing application (such as the dir command) when given the same file name string pattern. This is because FindFirstFile does no sorting of the search results .._

Comment: Retrieve the files. Then order them as you please.

Answer (score 3):

[FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418.aspx) doesn't retrieve files in any particular order:

> The FindFirstFile function opens a search handle and returns information about the first file that the file system finds [...]. This may or may not be the first file or directory that appears in a directory-listing application (such as the dir command) when given the same file name string pattern. **This is because FindFirstFile does no sorting of the search results.**

This is more explicitly documented for [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428.aspx):

> The order in which the search returns the files, such as alphabetical order, is not guaranteed, and is dependent on the file system. If the data must be sorted, the application must do the ordering after obtaining all the results.

So if you need a sorted list, you need to sort the results when done. The [WIN32_FIND_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740.aspx) structure contains timestamps. Record them and perform a [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) over the respective timestamps<sup>1</sup> once the results have been obtained.

---

<sup>1</sup> *This is based on the assumption that* "based on File data" *is a typo, and should read* "File date" *instead. If this is not the case, you need to provide a different comparison function to `std::sort`.*