# How can I sort files by the date they were created?

Tags: c++, sorting, winapi

I am new to c++, I am trying to sort the files present inside a specific folder by the date they were created using `FindFirstFiles()`. But later, I come to know the api will not support to sort the files on creation date. Could anyone please provide me some sample of code of how to implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch files in dataorder using FindFirstFiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320133/how-to-fetch-files-in-dataorder-using-findfirstfiles) and [How to sort files on creation date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43338490/1889329), asked yesterday and 4 hours ago. That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 1):

From LPWIN32_FIND_DATA (file information structure) you get as an output from FindFirstFile,you can fetch the time of every file in the directory,and as you iterate over the directory,you can insert each file handle in a map whose key would be the time of creation i.e. for 'x' file whatever its time of creation is you just insert it into a map.
The map by the virtue of its property would sort itself on the basis of key which here would be the TimeOfCreation